# Is it possible to open a file to a specific line number as formatted in grep -n results?

Tags: vim, grep, csh

I often use `grep` with the `-n` option to list line numbers, *e.g.*

```
$ grep -n xyz .*
/ext1/acheong/foo/bar/a.cc:42:    inline bool abc(int xyz);
/ext1/acheong/foo/bar/a.cc:43:    inline bool def(int xyz);
/ext1/acheong/foo/bar/b.cc:415:            int xyz = result;
/ext1/acheong/foo/bar/b.cc:490:                xyz += result;
$
```

Would it be possible to alias `vim` in such a way that doing

```
vim /ext1/acheong/foo/bar/b.cc:415
```

would open the file and seek line 415 automatically?

Is it possible in `csh`? (Yes, yes, `csh` brings out the devil and all that is unholy; but I've no choice...) An answer for other shells would be useful, too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, it's not an alias, you can use vim like this:

`vim +<LineNumberHere> fileName`

So, for example

```
vim +150 .bash_history
```

opens your .bash_history file (for bash), and navigates to line 150.

Incidentally, you can also do this with search terms. For example

```
vim +/MyTerm MyFile
```

opens MyFile and navigates to the first occurrence of MyTerm from the top.

Enjoy!

Comment: that should be "vim +/MyTerm MyFile"

Comment: Apologies for the late accept; I'd been wanting to make a `csh` alias that would map to the above form, but never got around to it.

Comment: this is great. It works with commands inside vim too: `:tabe +150 file`, `:tabe +/FooBar file`

Answer (score 4):

One solution to this is to use the [file_line.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2184) plugin, which lets you specify a file name and line number as an argument to Vim or on Vim's command line, just as you've shown.

Another is this script,

```
$ cat $(which vimgrep)
#!/bin/bash

tmp=$(mktemp)

cat > $tmp
```

```
exec < /dev/tty
```

```
vim --cmd 'let &efm=&gfm' -q $tmp "$@"
rm $tmp
```

which can be used like this:

```
$ grep -Hn xyz .* | vimgrep
```

and which loads all the matches into Vim's quickfix error list. See

```
:help quickfix.txt
```

Note the `-H` option to grep to ensure that the file name is included in grep's output even if `.*` expands to only one file name.

Comment: Due to the ad appearing right at the bottom of my screenheight for this thread, I never even saw this answer until today; apologies. I've already accepted the other answer, but Karma is on its way :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do your grepping from Vim itself:

```
:grep xyz *
```

then open the quickfix window:

```
:cw
```

Answer (score 1):

[vim-fetch](https://github.com/kopischke/vim-fetch) is able to open files at a specific location provided as colon separated values.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and resilient way:

1. Create a new file `~/.bin/vim` and paste the code below
2. Create shell alias: in `~/.bashrc` add line `alias vi=~/.bin/vim`

> This is called parameter substitution and will basically split the
>   provided parameters by '**:**' (colon).

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [[ ${1} == *":"* ]]; then
    vim ${1/:*/} -c "${1/*:/}"
else
    vim ${1}
fi
```

Then you could simply use it as:
`vim /ext1/acheong/foo/bar/b.cc:415`

Answer (score 0):

You can open it in BBEdit as long you have BBEdit define in `.bashrc`

```
$ grep EDITOR ~/.bashrc
export EDITOR="bbedit -w"
```

```
$ bbedit .bash_history:17:55
```

```
bbedit [Filepath/filename]:[line number]:[column number]
```